# Comparing a file's numeric content in if (linux)

Tags: bash

I want to compare a value from a .txt file with user's input

e.g.

```
read -p 'Enter the ammount you want to withdraw:' amm
if [ $amm > bank.txt ];
then
    echo 'You dont have enough money in your account'
else
    $bank - $amm >> bank.txt
fi
```

I don't know if its me asking the wrong question on google or there is just no answer to that action.

Comment: `>` is a redirection, not a numeric comparison; you're redirecting the output of `[ $amm ]` to the file `bank.txt`

Comment: that is to say, `[ $amm > bank.txt ]` is *exactly the same as* `[ $amm ] > bank.txt` (except less portable, as being able to put redirections anywhere in a command is a bashism).

Comment: Consider http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

Comment: ...and make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: btw, as an aside, this isn't a very secure bank -- it's prone to race conditions: `echo "$(( bank - amm ))" >bank.txt` will write your post-withdrawal sum to a file, but not as an atomic operation; without locking, someone running 15 withdrawals at the exact same time could have all of them succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the output of a command as if it were actually in the script itself. In this case, you want the content of a file, so you can use:

```
if [[ ${amm} -gt $(cat bank.txt) ]]
```

or, better yet, to avoid the extra `cat` process:

```
if [[ ${amm} -gt $(<bank.txt) ]]
```

This executes the command `cat bank.txt`, captures its output and places that into the command being executed. So, if that file contained the single line `42`, it would be as if your command was:

```
if [[ ${amm} -gt 42 ]]
```

Of course, should that file not exist or should it contain something other than a single number, that method won't work so well. You should probably be checking the content before using it.

And `bash` also provides a way of doing this with `((...))` rather than `[[...]]`, which may fit in more naturally with what you want to express.

```
if (( ${amm} > $(<bank.txt) ))
```

but I actually prefer the `[[...]]` variant myself.

Comment: No probs, @Νίκος, καλά νέο έτος - that's probably hideously deformed but it's the best I can do with my limited knowledge :-)